# ControlsFX Position of AutCompletePopup is incorrect

Tags: java, css, javafx, controlsfx

I have an AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding object for one of my TextFields. The position of the AutoCompletePopup is offset from the TextField by a good margin, from other images of the popup I can see this is NOT supposed to be the case. What could possible reasons for this be? The TextField is inside an AnchorPane with a padding of 10 on the bottom. I figured that might be it and have tried removing the padding but the issue persists. Is there a way to override the position of the popup? I have tried getting the AutoCompletePopup and setting the styling on it via:

```
binding.getTextFieldBinding().getAutoCompletionPopup().setStyle("-fx-padding: 100 0 0 0;");
```

This was just to see if I could see a difference, the above styling makes no visible difference in the position of the popup. Is it possible to set the position through styling to begin with? I am okay with a "hacky" solution that simply move the popup up by a few pixels.

An image of the popup position can be seen here: [image: Visual problem]

EDIT:
If any additional information is necessary, let me know.

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pop up should be directly under the text field by default. Maybe a "hacky" solution is to just use the [`translateYProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/transform/Translate.html#yProperty) like this:

**styling.css:**

```css
.auto-complete-popup {
    -fx-translate-y: -10; /* Move the pop up 10 pixels higher */
}
```

Comment: The issue seems to be CSS-related, as disabling the stylesheet applied to the scene fixes the issue. I tried adding the styling to my current CSS file and it fixes the problem for me! Thank you!